# Where do I look for Linux kernel module documentation?

Tags: linux-kernel, documentation, kernel-module

Where do I look for Linux kernel module documentation?

For example, I've tried googling the module `iwlagn`, but I cannot find anything that tells me about available options. Where do I look?

Comment: Is `iwlagn` just a possibly poor example, or are you primarily interested in this specific module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two authoritative sources for module information:

1. `modinfo iwlagn` gives you the list of options, with terse description of each.
2. Get the kernel source (using your distribution's tools, or from [www.kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org/)), search for `iwlagn` source there, usually, the source of the module contains at least some info about its options (search for options available in step #1 inside the source file). You don't really need to understand the code, just read the comments.

And of course, google is your friend here too, once you found the options of interest to you, googling them together with the module name sometimes gives useful results.

Comment: Is there a website that lists all the kernel modules and what they do? I only found this: https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/

Answer (score 0):

You normally should not directly configure your modules with options, rather you should use the software your OS provides for configuration. In case of wireless LAN you'd better use `iwconfig` and you can find all available options in man pages for this utility.

I just binged for your module and found [this description](http://wiki.debian.org/iwlagn) that I found rather complete. You should have seen it too. Did you miss anything there?